# go to page and open modal javascript

Tags: javascript, html

The goal is to go to a page and show a modal from that page.

Is there a way to have this execute after the page has successfully loaded?

```
//load page
window.location.href = 'foobar.html';

//wait until page is ready then open modal?
$(window).ready(function () {
  console.log('did it work?');
  $('#someModal').modal('show');
});
```

I listed the javascript file in the html page but this just isn't working. Everything is happening in the same document window from the initial page.

**ANSWER**

I decided to get the previous url and search for a substring to trigger the modal to show on the second page.

```
//first js script for the first html page
window.location.href = 'foobar.html';

//second js script for the second html page
$(document).ready(function () {

    var prev_url = document.referrer;

    if (prev_url.includes('substring')){
        $('#someModal').modal('show');
    }
});
```

Comment: redirect to some page with request parameter , then on the page check request parameter , if exist show modal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you for the suggestions.

I thought of a way to get this to work!
On the second page document reload, I will get the last url string and see if it contains a substring. If yes, show the modal. Seems to be working :)

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    var prev_url = document.referrer;

    if (prev_url.includes('substring')){
        $('#someModal').modal('show');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, javascript only exists in between page loads, every new page load will clear all executing javascript code. If you want to simulate a page load, you can use the History api, which will push a new entry onto the browser's back button, and then run code after that. instead of assigning values to `window.location`, you will need to call [`pushState`](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/html5/history-api.html#pushstate) and give it some arguments as described in the link, then proceed to call your modal code.

for example,

```js
window.history.pushState({}, window.document.title, 'foobar.html');
$('#someModal').modal('show');
```

Answer (score 0):

You should separate the scripts. 
1rst page:

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
window.location.href="foobar.html";
});
```

2nd page:

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
     $('#someModal').modal('show');
});
```

I hope this works for you.

Comment: Your suggestion sparked an idea. Thank you